# Requested registry access is not allowed when using impersonation

Tags: c#, powershell, impersonation

I'm editing a site that we use to create project folders on our file servers.
Since none uses C# that much we want to change so that it just executes a PowerShell script to make it more simple for us in the future if we need to change anything.

At first i got this error on execution

> Requested registry access is not allowed.

Then I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637128/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-when-attempting-to-run-powershell-scr), and I added the Runspace like it said. This removed the issue and it started working when I created the folders on places where my normal user account already can through explorer.

But it doesn't create the folders when I try to create the folders on places where only the account I use with the impersonation has access to create the folders.

Here's the code:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Impersonator imp = new Impersonator("username", "domain", "Password");
        string server = DropDownListSite.SelectedValue + @"FIL001";
        string company = DropDownListCompanies.SelectedValue;
        string site = DropDownListSite.SelectedValue;
        string PX = TextBoxPX.Text;
        string description = TextBoxDescription.Text;

        string vartDescription = "'" + TextBoxDescription.Text + "'";
        // Initialize PowerShell engine
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        shell.Runspace = runspace;

        // Add the script to the PowerShell object
        Impersonator imp = new Impersonator("username", "domain", "Password");
        shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\ITAdmin\\Scripts\\SkapaUppdrag.ps1 -Bolag " + DropDownListCompanies.Text + " -Site " + DropDownListSite.Text + " -PX " + TextBoxPX.Text + " -Description " + vartDescription);

        // Execute the script
        var results = shell.Invoke();

        // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
        // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            // We use a string builder ton create our result text
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var psObject in results)
            {
                // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                // Add \r\n for line breaks
                builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }

            // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
            LabelStatus.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. Exactly _what_ doesn't work? And I suggest you get rid of that try/catch block if you ever want to find out what's actually wrong.

Comment: I does not create the folders on the file servers where my logged in user has no access to create folders. The Impersonated user allthough has that access so its like it doesn't use the Impersonated user to create the folder.

Comment: I've added 
     $env:Username | Out-String
to the powershell script to see who's running the script and it show the user i'm logged in to the computer with, so it doesn't run the script as the impersonated user right?

Comment: Lets say like this, what i want is to create folders on a share with a different account (a service account) that's the only one who's allowed to create folders on the share, i want c# to run the powershell script with the credential of this service account so that i can easily add other things it should do in the future that normal account are not allowed to do but this service account is.